# Solr 5.4.1 Merge Index real time

Tags: solr

I have two sources - Sitecore web index (core 1) and a database table (core 2). I have created core 3 which is a merge of core1 and core 2.

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=mergeindexes&core=core3&srcCore=sitecore_web_index&srcCore=core2

But when someone publishes a page on Sitecore, the sitecore web index gets updated but not the merged core. How can get the real time data with the merge? Is there a way?

If I run this on the browser and stop and start Solr I see the data. But this is not possible on production when pages will get edited and published.

Thanks 
Kalpana

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small plugin that listens to commit events by using the [SolrEventListener](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#SolrEventListener) interface. It would still require you to merge the complete indices, which may not be effective if you have indexes that are on the larger side.

Another option is to index to both cores (which Sitecore might not be able to do - I'm not familiar with Sitecore), or, depending on your requirements, using the sharding support to search both core1 and core2 without core3 might also be an option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Merging indexes every time there is a publish is not an effective option like you have mentioned. I already have both the cores indexed, I am not sure of a way to combine the results into one result set. You have mentioned Sharding. Can I add it to the Request Handler on Solrconfig.xml?

Comment: This does not seem to work - I get 0 results 

<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
     <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="shards">localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_web_index,localhost:8983/solr/SharePoint_All</str>
     </lst>
    </requestHandler>

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler"> 
<!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these will be overridden by parameters in the request --> 
<lst name="defaults"> 
<str name="shards">localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_web_index,localhost:8983/solr/SharePo‌​int_All</str> 
</lst> 
</requestHandler>
```